# Where is the Web Deployment MSI?

Tags: iis-7, web-deployment-project

I'm following a set of instructions where a line reads:

> Launch the x86 or x64 Web Deployment
>   Tool’s MSI.

My IIS's Web Platform Installer verifies that i have Web Deployment Tool 1.1 but I can't find a location to launch it.

Comment: JFTR for whatever that's worth...i found myself guilty of 'recipe-itis' - depending on the tutorial too much. The steps i got caught up on where looking for the Tool's UI but the MSI referenced was the installer of the beta version - since replaced by the WebPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy`